# Symfony2 - Check if command is running

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to check if a symfony command is already running?
I have a command that runs without timeout and consuming data and i need to know if the command is already running.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a lock to ensure that the command only runs once at a time. Symfony provides a `LockHandler` helper for that but you can easily do this with plain PHP as well.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\LockHandler;

class WhateverCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure() { }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $lock = new LockHandler('a_unique_id_for_your_command');
        if (!$lock->lock()) {
            $output->writeln('This command is already running in another process.');

            return 0;
        }

        // ... do some task

        $lock->release();
    }
}
```

Comment: A lock handler like @Stefan suggested is definitely the most effective one, so you avoid race conditions and it is scalable if you want to run multiple once with different ids or distributing the data.

Answer (score 0):

On later versions of Symfony you can use [LockableTrait](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/console/lockable_trait.html):

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateContentsCommand extends Command
{
use LockableTrait;

// ...

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    if (!$this->lock()) {
        $output->writeln('The command is already running in another process.');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

    // If you prefer to wait until the lock is released, use this:
    // $this->lock(null, true);

    // if not released explicitly, Symfony releases the lock
    // automatically when the execution of the command ends
    $this->release();

    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
}
```